# htaccess RewriteRule - Not allowing underscore (_) in URL

Tags: php, html, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^question/([a-zA-Z0-9_-?]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-?]+)?$ question.php?postid=$1&url_title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I tried all RegEx for underscore(`_`) but still this is not working. It shows me:

> `404 - Page Not Found` Error

Comment: Note that you can use `\w` for an alphanumberic character. It is shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: What is URL you're entering in browser to test and where does `question.php` exist?

Comment: RewriteRule ^question/([\w])/?([\w])?$ question.php?postid=$1&url_title=$2 [L,QSA]
this is also not working

Comment: @AnilKumar I did not mean it will fix your problem, but it will make your RegEx shorter and more easily readable

Comment: http://www.proprofs.com/discuss/q/question/27959/question-337w_
this is url. you can check here

Comment: Is `/q/` a real directory?

Comment: @ Druzion thanx for valuable information it iwll make it short but at this time  i wann to allow underscore any how

Comment: yes q is real directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule at top of your .htaccess inside `/q/` directory :

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^question/([\w-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ question.php?postid=$1&url_title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: bro..
RewriteRule ^question/([\w-]+)/?([\w-]+)/?$ question.php?postid=$1&url_title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
this is also not working

Comment: Where is this htaccess located and where is question.php located?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^question/([\w-]+)/?([\w-]+)/?$ question.php?postid=$1&url_title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
top on the htaccess fle 
in q/ directory

Comment: any other possibility for not working...
url working fine after removing underscore

Comment: Exact same rule works fine on my Apache. Can you provide full .htaccess from `q/` directory

Comment: let me know you skype id. i can share my screen. if u dont mind , sir ;)